# JavaFX: Is there an integer property allowing null values and providing methods like greaterThan and lessThan?

Tags: java, javafx, properties, null

In JavaFX, there is an `IntegerProperty` class which inherits methods such as `greaterThan` and `lessThan` that return a `BooleanBinding`. However, null values are not allowed since it stores the value as an `int` (hence the separate `IntegerProperty` class).

Conversely, `ObjectProperty<Integer>` allows null values but does not provide such methods.

Is there a way of having both of these: **allowing null values** while being able to **obtain a `BooleanBinding`** (or similar) **comparing two properties** (perhaps using a `Comparator`, for example)?

Answer (score 3):

The static method [`IntegerProperty.integerProperty(Property<Integer>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/IntegerProperty.html#integerProperty-javafx.beans.property.Property-) creates an `IntegerProperty` from a `Property<Integer>` and establishes a bidirectional binding between them. In this case, you only have one option as to how to treat null values in the `Property<Integer>`: they are treated as zero.

If that works for your use case, then you can just do:

```
Property<Integer> age = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
BooleanBinding canVote = IntegerProperty.integerProperty(age).greaterThanOrEqualTo(18);
```

Otherwise, using only the standard API, you need to create the bindings by hand:

```
Property<Integer> age = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
BooleanBinding canVote = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
    if (age.get() == null) {
        return false ;
    } else {
        return age.get().intValue() >= 18 ;
    }
}, age);
```

The other option is to use (or write...) a third-party binding library. For example, using [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) (a reactive programming API for JavaFX which incorporates some binding APIs), you could do

```
Property<Integer> age = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
Val<Boolean> canVote = Val.map(age, a -> a >= 18);
```

Here `canVote` is a `Val<Boolean>` (`Val` is an `ObservableValue`) 
which is "empty" if `age` contains null, and `true` or `false` accordingly otherwise. You can do

```
ObservableValue<Boolean> canVote = Val.map(age, a -> a >= 18).orElseConst(false);
```

to force it to have a value if `age` contains `null`.